# How can we recognize Moses' original scroll?

Tags: moshe-rabbeinu, sefer-torah

Let's imagine we excavate the Temple Mount area and find an Ark with a 3500-year-old scroll in good condition.

How would we know if it is the original scroll Moses wrote (*besides being accompanied by two sapphire tablets*)?

Comment: I had always heard that the scroll which Apostemos burned on 17 Tammuz (Taanis 4:6) was the one which Moshe burned, but I can’t find a source for it at the moment.

Comment: If it is found with the other items listed in Sefer Emek HaMelech, it would be accompanied by the container of Manna, the staff of Aharon and the ashes of the red heifer from Moshe together with the tablets you mentioned.

Comment: @YaacovDeane Right, as I mentioned, that would be circumstantial - could it have been replaced?

Comment: @AlBerko That tradition is also recorded in the teachings of  Eliyahu HaNavi in  Eliyahu Rabbah. As I would understand that, we are supposed to accept that they are going to be found together. (teachings of a Prophet)